# To Laugh Often and Much

Tags: punctuation, coordination, semicolons

> **To laugh often and much**;
>   **to win the respect of intelligent people
>
>   and the affection of children**;
>   to earn the appreciation of honest critics
>   and endure the betrayal of false friends;
>   to appreciate beauty;
>   to find the best in others;
>   to leave the world a bit better,
>   whether by a healthy child,
>   a garden patch or a redeemed social condition;
>   to know that even one life has breathed easier
>   because you have lived.
>   
>   This is to have succeeded.

Are these sentences called something specific, in grammar? These don't seem to have any subject. Can they be thought of as complete sentences?

Comment: They are definitely ***not*** complete sentences.  The first "sentence" is an enumeration of infinitive phrases.  They aren't subjects, they aren't objects.  Example of an object: "to err is human" -- "to err" is a direct object of the verb "is".

Comment: Or maybe I'm mistaken about "to err", which might actually be a subject.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Yes. In fact, *be* does not take any object: it takes a predicate complement.

Comment: @StoneyB, ah, so is "to err" in that expression a predicate complement or is it a subject?

Comment: @StoneyB, and in "be all you can be" what is "all you can be" if not an object?  "Come on, be a man!" (a man - a predicate complement?)

Comment: @VictorBazarov In *To err is human*, *To err* is the subject and *human* is the PC. In *Be a man*, *you* is the deleted subject and *a man* is the PC.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Remember that *be* is always intransitive.  The complements it takes are never objects.  *Predicative complement* is Huddleston & Pullum's term; *subject complement* is a more traditional term, although keep in mind that 'subject complements' are not subjects.

Comment: @VictorBazarov What snailboat says ... another term is *subject-oriented predicate complement*. There are also object-oriented predicate complements (but not with *be*).

Comment: @saySay Keep in mind that *sentence* is something of an artificial concept.  We don't use periods and capital letters when we speak.  If someone were to say your example out loud, and two different people were to write it down, they might use punctuation very differently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one long "sentence". Replace the full stop with a comma or dash, and you have an unusually long but otherwise unremarkable example of **left dislocation**.

> CANONICAL FORM: To laugh often is to have succeeded.
>   LEFT-DISLOCATED FORM: To laugh often, this is to have succeeded.

In your example, the dislocated subject is a list of infinitival phrases: *to laugh ..., to win ..., to earn ..., to appreciate ..., to leave ..., to know ...* .

Comment: Ah. So, what I gathered is that a sentence is somewhat artificial. “Canonical” and “Left-Dislocated Form”. . . interesting! I don’t think I’ve read infinitival phrases used as subjects so often. So, for example, *to laugh*, or *to laugh often* I guess I think of as the subject? I guess I have three questions to clarify: I thought subjects require nouns? I guess, grammatically, you can place a full stop (;, here) even though I thought full stops only get used after a noun and intransitive verb, or noun, transitive verb, and object?

Comment: And, if I may ask, where did you find this citation so that I may maybe try to read it a bit?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's very rhetorical. 2) Various sorts of subordinate clauses, full or reduced, can act as subjects. 3) Contexts like this really fall outside the purposes for which the codified punctuation you read about in style manuals is designed. 4) There's a Wikipedia article on [Dislocation (syntax)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax)) you may find helpful.

Comment: Wait, what's rhetorical? So, *to laugh* (subject) in *to laugh often and much* (noun phrase?) same with (to win the respect of intelligent people, etc.?). And so is this really more of a list with (;'s), when I would usually see commas? As I don't really see them as sentences in that they seem just like infinitival phrases, or noun phrases? So, like I would think of it like *To laugh often and much, to win the respect of intelligent people, and the affection of children . . .—This is to have succeeded.*

Comment: I guess I don't get how he can, (in a grammatically correct way), use (;'s) as they aren't complete sentences, and (;'s) signify to me (not sure if they get called a full stop) an end to a complete sentence.

Comment: @saySay Semicolons are routinely used instead of commas for lists of long phrases which are internally broken by commas.

Comment: Ah. So, I may think of this as a list, one which contains a series of infinitival phrases that seem to operate as noun phrases, to me, and, all apart of one "sentence", if *lived* wasn't separated from *This is to have succeeded.*, by a full stop. I guess I find it odd he wrote all that, all those (;'s), a list of left-dislocated noun phrases ended by a full stop period, when it isn't a complete sentence.

Comment: @saySay Think of the punctuation here not as a formal but as a rhetorical sign, a sort of 'stage direction': it tells the reader how to hear the phrasing  while reading.

Answer (score 0):

Periods (.) are full stops.  They indicate the ends of statements.

Question marks (?) indicate the ends of questions.

Exclamation marks (!) indicate the ends of exclamatory statements.

Semi-colons (;) are **not** full stops.  They separate related thoughts that are part of the same sentence.

Commas (,) are less significant than semi-colons.  Commas are used to separate items in lists.

According to http://emerson-legacy.tamu.edu/Ephemera/Success.html, the original poster's quotation is adapted from Bessie A. Stanley's poem "[What is Success?](https://books.google.com/books?id=2bFJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1&cad=3#v=onepage)", which was published in 1911:

> He has achieved success,
>   who has lived well, laughed often, and loved much;
>   who has gained the respect of intelligent men
>   and the love of little children;
>   who has filled his niche and accomplished his task,
>   whether by an improved poppy, a perfect poem, or a rescued soul;
>   who has never lacked an appreciation
>   of earth's beauty, or failed to express it;
>   who has always looked for the best in others
>   and given the best he had;
>   whose life was an inspiration
>   and whose memory a benediction.

Comment: So, if I write, He confused me; he was always late. this is considered one sentence? As, (;’s) are not full stops, and they separate related thoughts that are part of the same sentence?

Comment: @saySay -- Your comment is worthy of its own question.  By the way, each half of your example is a complete sentence.  (You could replace the semi-colon with a period, capitalize the second "he", and be grammatically correct.)  I do not see the relationship between the two halves of your example.  When using a semi-colon, you should make sure that there is a clear relationship between the thoughts.